# How to use EGOImageLoading with ASIHTTPRequest ? where is the viewDidLoad in EGOImageLoading?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, asihttprequest, egoimageview

I want use the EGOImageLoading to load pictures to a UITableVIew.
I got the URLs by ASIHTTPRequest in the viewDidLoad function and put them in an Array.

I've read the demo of EGOImageLoading , but cannot find the viewDidLoad function?
Could some one tell me if i need a viewDidLoad function? or just write in the awakeFromNib function?

Answer (score 3):

You have to take custom cell and set `EGOImageView` there see following Code.

```
-(void)drawImageView {

    memberImg =[[EGOImageView alloc] initWithPlaceholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbnail.png"]];
    memberImg.frame = CGRectMake(5.0f, 7.0f,52.0f,63.0f);
    memberImg.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    memberImg.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0;
    [self.contentView addSubview:memberImg];
}
-(void)setMemberPhoto:(NSString *)photo
{
    memberImg.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:photo];
}
```

add above code in custom cell class .m file and add following code in `celForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
static NSString *temp= @"AlbumCustomCell";
        AlbumCustomCell *cellheader = (AlbumCustomCell *)[albumTableObj dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:temp];
        if (cellheader == nil) {
            NSArray* nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AlbumCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cellheader = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cellheader.showsReorderControl = NO;
            cellheader.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cellheader.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            [cellheader drawImageView];
           }
[cellheader setMemberPhoto:photos];
return cellheader;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`EGOImageLoading` is used for loading images asynchronously and does not require any other outside networking libraries to function. All you do is set the `imageURL`, and the download is handled automatically. You do not need to use `ASIHTTPRequest` to load images if you are using `EGOImageLoading`.

In addition to that, `viewDidLoad` is a `UIViewController` function that does not have anything to do with either of these things.

Comment: can you please take a look over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708064/how-to-load-multiple-image-in-scrollview-from-egoimageloading-like-instagram-in? i am facing some problem while implementing `EGOImageLoading`